# Is there a way to change font color of Jradiobuttons using the UImanager

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, uimanager

I know I how to change the font of a JRadioButton using UIManager and I know how to change the color of a JRadioButton, one button at a time.   However is there a way, using the UIManager to change all JradioButtons in my application so that the font is, say white, instead of the default black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the `UIDefaults` early in your program:

```
UIDefaults uiDefaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
uiDefaults.put("RadioButton.foreground", new ColorUIResource(Color.white));
```

Just be sure to use a contrasting color for the background.

Comment: NB: not all Look & Feel implementations display such changes; testing will be required.